# What does "ratio doloris" mean?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning

What does *ratio doloris* mean?
I want to translate *ratio doloris* from Latin to English in all contexts for which it would make grammatical sense, because I want to know if *-is* is the correct suffix for *dolor* in the following context:

I am attempting to shorten a phrase similar to, if not exactly, *Et ratio in dolore est* into 2 words.

Credit for the phrase goes to [GIVE_ME_UR_B00BZ](https://www.reddit.com/r/latin/comments/6go2ks/help_with_translating_a_saying_to_the_effect_of/dirzksk/) on the Latin subreddit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The suffix *-is* indicates genitive in the third declension.
That is, *doloris* means "of pain".

The word *ratio* is complicated.
The dictionary by Lewis and Short lists the following translations under [*ratio*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=ratio&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059):
reckoning, account, calculation, computation, list, roll, register, sum, number, business matter, transaction, business, matter, affair, interest, advantage, relation, reference, respect, regard, concern, consideration, care, course, conduct, procedure, mode, manner, method, fashion, plan, condition, nature, kind, sort, way, judgment, understanding, reason, ground, motive, showing cause, argument, reasonableness, propriety, law, rule, order, conformity, theory, doctrine, system, science, knowledge, philosophy, view, opinion, proof, argumentation, reasoning.
I may have missed something, but the point should be clear: *ratio* can mean an enormous number of different things, depending on context.
(There are also other online dictionaries; see [this list](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79).)

The word [*dolor*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=dolor&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) is clearer, and "pain" is a good overall translation.
Some translations picked from L&S:
pain, ache, distress, grief, affliction, sorrow, anguish, trouble, vexation, mortification, wrath, animosity, anger, resentment, pathos.

The phrase *ratio doloris* means "*ratio* of *dolor*", but it can also be interpreted as "*ratio* towards *dolor*" or "*ratio* caused by *dolor*".
Now if you replace *ratio* and *dolor* with the possible translations offered above, you get a huge number of different readings, and without context any one of them is possible.

Without context, my first guesses at the meaning would be "reason for pain" or "nature/manner of pain".

If you want to know what *Et ratio in dolore est* means and whether that is a good translation for "There is purpose in pain", I recommend asking a separate question.
It would be a good question, but it's cleaner to keep different questions separate, whether or not related.